# bash, dash and string comparison

Tags: bash, dash-shell, string-comparison

I am trying to compare two strings in a simple shell script.
I was using `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`, and after countless hours of debugging, it turns out sh (which is actually dash) can't handle this block of code:

```
if [ "$var" == "string" ]
then
    do something
fi
```

What is a portable way to compare strings using `/bin/sh`? I know I can always do the opposite by using !=, but I am wondering about a cleaner, portable way.

Comment: You can use `[[ $var == "string" ]]` , which is POSIX, but optional (afaik). Or you use `[ "$var" = "string" ]` . Note the `""` around the variable in the single-bracket edition: it's required in case `$var` is empty

Comment: The important part is the quotes around `$var` as litb mentioned. Without the quotes, `[ $var = "value" ]` becomes `[ = "value" ]` which confuses the shell pretty horrendously. You will probably see an error like _"[: =: unary operator expected"_ when you encounter an empty variable otherwise.

Comment: I understand about "$var" vs. $var, my problem was == vs. =

Comment: [[ ]] is reserved by POSIX, but not at all defined. It's just reserved because it's a Korn feature I think.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`dash` is a very strict POSIX shell, if it work in `dash` it is almost certain it would work in other POSIX shell.

Try:

```
if [ "$var" = "string" ]
then
    some_command
fi
```

Comment: If you are thinking "what's the difference here to the syntax in the question": it's using `=` instead of `==`

Comment: How can you use wildcards in this example?
I tried if [ "$OSTYPE" = "linux"* ]; then but it doesn't get linux-arm, for example...

Answer (score 9):

Why is there even a possibility that your script will be run by the "wrong" shell? I would think you could make that a pre-requisite of your product by using the standard sh-bang line at the top of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Even if a user *uses* a different shell, the other shells are generally still there and, if not, simply complain and state that they are a pre-req.

Exactly the same way that a specific kernel level, or the existence of awk, can be a pre-req.

For your specific question, I believe both `sh` and `bash` allow the single '=' to be used for string comparisons - that is POSIX behavior:

```
if [ "a" = "a" ]; then
    echo yes
fi

yes
```

Comment: *"Why is there even a possibility that your script will be run by the "wrong" shell? "* - Is it possible to control which shell is used by Autoconf? (That's the reason I'm searching for the answer)

Answer (score 6):

Use `=` instead of `==`. Comparisons are handled by test(1). `/usr/bin/[` is typically a link to `/usr/bin/test` . The only difference is that if you use `[` in a shell script, the `]` is required as well.

Note that bash has a built-in `test`/`[`, so it doesn't actually use `/usr/bin/test`.

Comment: Are there any official spec about the builtin *test* and single or double equal sign?

Answer (score 1):

The answers already posted are certainly correct, but it may be worthwhile to note that occasionally parameter expansion can serve the same purpose with perhaps some additional flexibility.

```
% p() { printf 'notvar = %b\n' "${notvar##"${string1}"}${string2}" ; }
% string1='some stuff about things\c'
% string2='some different stuff maybe'
% notvar="$string1" p
> 'some different stuff maybe'
% notvar="$string2" p
> 'some stuff about things'
```

Ok, so the above isn't super-useful as is, but also consider that you can use the similar methods for testing variables in here-documents, in-line variable assignments if necessary (to a degree...), or even just as a shorter (and faster!) means of writing your first statement.

```
[ ! "${var##"string"}" ] && _MATCH || _NOMATCH
```

Or even...

```
[ ${#var#*"${s=string}"} -lt ${#var} ] && _SUB_STRING_TEST=TRUE
```

Possibly even...

```
% p() { printf '%s is %s of %s' "$2" "${var_chk-not}" "$1"
> }<<HEREDOC
> ${in="${1##*"${2}"*}"}
> ${in:-
>     ${in="${1##"${2}"}"}
>     ${in:-${var_chk=all}
>     ${var_chk=some}
> }
> HEREDOC
%
```

Comment: Not sure I see the big benefit of these techniques unless you're trying to win an obfuscation contest.

Comment: Wow...I need someone to ELI5 :)

Answer (score -3):

you can use awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{
 string1="test"
 string2="tes1t"
 if(s1==s2){
    print "same string"
 }else{
    print "not same"
 }
}'
```